# Obtaining live data from website... Jsoup? OCR?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, screen-scraping, ocr

I need to obtain some live football stats from betting websites - using java. My first thought was to use Jsoup, but doesn't seem to be giving me any output.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it the type of webpage I'm trying to scrape? If so, could I use OCR instead to get my required stats?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.betfair.com/sport/football/event?eventId=27446056").get();

String shots = doc.select("#in-game-stats > div:nth-child(1) > div.si-home-value").text();
System.out.println(shots);
```

Comment: It's going to be impossible to tell without the page source, which looks like it's probably changed in the few hours since you posted the question.

Comment: For the page source you can go on to any event on this page: https://www.betfair.com/sport/inplay

The events obviously change every few hours as matches finish etc.

Answer (score -1):

This is a tutorial video for what you want:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tI1qGwhn_bs&ab_channel=ShaneLee

```
public class Stock {

public Stock() {
    final String url =
            "https://sharestobeclosed.telegraph.co.uk/indices/financials/index/MCX";

    try {
        final Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        for (Element row : document.select(
                "table.tablesorter.full tr")) {
            if (row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text().equals("")) {
                continue;
            } else {
                final String ticker =
                        row.select("td:nth-of-type(1)").text();
                final String name =
                        row.select("td:nth-of-type(2)").text();
                final String tempPrice =
                        row.select("td.right:nth-of-type(3)").text();
                final String tempPrice1 =
                        tempPrice.replace(",", "");
//                    final double price = Double.parseDouble(tempPrice1);

                System.out.println(ticker + " " + name + " " + tempPrice1);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}